# Полоса прокрутки?

Tags: css

Почему на мониторе с разрешением по ширине 1366px при использовании данного кода, страница с такой же шириной (1366px) не вмещается в экран браузера — появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки и к родительскому блоку добавляется отрицательный `margin-right: -40px`.

```css
.main-wrapper {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 1366px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner_wrapper {
    max-height: 2054px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="inner_wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `max-width` и будет счастье!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBBMJK

```
.main-wrapper {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    max-width: 1366px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner_wrapper {
    max-height: 2054px;
}

<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="inner_wrapper">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Задайте `body { margin: 0; }` чтобы обнулить отступ, установленный по умолчанию.
Проверьте масштаб страницы.

Всё работает:

```
.main-wrapper {
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    max-width: 1366px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner_wrapper {
    max-height: 2054px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="inner_wrapper">Some text</div>
</div>
```